# Postman - Validate value from Response and print on Console

Tags: postman, postman-testcase

From below Response, I want to fetch the value of "responseCode" and store temporarily. If a value is 1 then on Console, I want to write "Test PASS". Can anyone share code for this test?

```
{
   "data":{
      "transactionId":"$1"
   },
   "responseMessage":"Transaction successfully done. Transaction Id : txn_15594028419901124218",
   "responseCode":1
}
```

I tried to use the following code to set the variable:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody); 
pm.globals.set("responseCode",jsonData.data.responseCode);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.globals.set("responseCode",jsonData.data.responseCode);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basic `test` would check that value in the response, store the variable and also write `Test PASS` to the console

```
pm.test("Check the Response Code is 1", () => {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().responseCode).to.eql(1);
    pm.globals.set("responseCode", pm.response.json().responseCode)
    console.log("Test PASS")
});
```

This doesn't account for the test failing and writing `Test FAIL` to the console, you kind of get that anyway in the Postman UI.

If you didn't want to wrap this in a `test`, you could just do something like:

```
if(pm.response.json().responseCode === 1){
    pm.globals.set("responseCode", pm.response.json().responseCode)
    console.log("Test PASS")
}
else {
    console.log("Test FAIL")
}
```

Comment: Hi Danny, Thank you so much for providing solution. It worked for me.

Comment: Can you accept this as the answer, to close out the question.